# Lost git changes on local copy

Tags: git, github, information-retrieval

I cloned a repo, then made some changes on the local copy,
I wanted to upload to a new branch.
so I run the following commands:

```
git add .
git checkout -b new-branch
git add .
git stash
git push origin new-branch
```

All of the sudden ,my changes are gone , the repo has the same structure as I cloned it.

How to retrieve my changes??

Comment: Sounds to me like you stashed your changes. If that's the case, you can get them back using `git stash apply`

Comment: Ok, I still on the command line, I will try it.

Comment: I got them back, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you stashed your changes, which puts them in a temporary stack data structure. You can get them back by using `git stash apply`, which applies the top of the stack back to your files.

See `git help stash` for more info. In particular, checkout `git stash list` and `git stash show` for commands to see what's in the stash stack.

TBH, something like SourceTree can also be nice for quickly glancing through the stash to see what's there.